# Unsubscribing from events on page change

Tags: events, angular, ionic2

When I keep adding pages to navigation stack, more and more instances of SimpleComponent class are created. For this reason I subscribe more than once to "ev" event and fire code more than once.

You can check that by going "there" and "back" in my plunker example and firing event in different situations (check console warnings for results). You can also see that even when you move back to the top of the navigation stack, you still have your subscription.

ionViewWillLeave is not working probably because it's not the actual view that I'm leaving

I wonder what should I do in order to avoid that? I want the SimpleComponent to be included like old-style AngularJS directive as I use it in my application many times.

[Here is plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l1bCu3CrSP0OYZMjRUvq?p=preview)

```
export class SimpleComponent {
  constructor(private ev: Events) {
    this.ev.subscribe('ev', e => {
      console.warn(e[0]);
    });  
  }
}


// home.ts template
    <simple-component></simple-component>
    <button (click)="go()">Go next page</button>
    <button (click)="raiseEv()">Raise Event</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement `OnDestroy` and there you can `unsubscribe` from `ev`:

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

export class SimpleComponent implements OnDestroy {

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ev.unsubscribe();
}
```

From [Angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html):

> Put cleanup logic in ngOnDestroy, the logic that must run before Angular destroys the directive. This is the time to notify another part of the application that this component is going away. This is the place to free resources that won't be garbage collected automatically. Unsubscribe from observables and DOM events. Stop interval timers. Unregister all callbacks that this directive registered with global or application services. We risk memory leaks if we neglect to do so.

Comment: Well, this is helpful as far as I go one step in (add one page to navigation stack) and then return back (remove page from nav stack). What about I push 5 pages onto nav stack, or switch between tabs? It's more ionic2 issue and how it handles tab switching and nav stack pushing.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to move my code responsible for handling after-event-received action to @Injectable and that solved the issue